# Adding custom Annotaionview in map ios

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I want to add custom annotation view in map view.I have used `MKMapview`.

Can I add any view with animation as annotation view too?

I have used delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate method `viewForAnnotation:` something like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapVieww viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *pinAnnotationView = nil;

    if (annotation != mapVieww.userLocation )
    {
        pinAnnotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotation.title];

        if ( pinAnnotationView == nil )
        {
            pinAnnotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotation.title];
            pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            if([pinAnnotationView.annotation.title isEqualToString: NSLocalizedString(@"Start", @"startPin Title")])
            {
                [pinAnnotationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin_Green"]];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pinAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

    }

    return pinAnnotationView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! well can i use animation in annotaionview too?

Comment: Sure. You can simply use UIView animations to do whatever you want with the annotations.